# use xmlstarlet in shell script to read script variable value and insert in outpu xml file under specific section if the string is not present there

Tags: xml, shell, xslt, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

The parse yaml utility which I used in my shell script produces variables as below  by eval command

```
policy1_name='ipfilter'
policy1_scope='api'
policy1_apiname='apiname'
policy1_inboundsession='rate-limit-by-key calls="25" renewal-period="60"
counter-key="@\(Regex.Match\(context.xxx.xxxx.GetValueOrDefault\("X-xxxxxxx-For",""\), @"^[.0-9]*"\)?.Value\)'
policy1_outboundsession_ipAddressesFrom='1xxxxxxxx'
policy1_outboundsession_ipAddressesTo='1yyyyyyy'
policy1_=' policy1_name policy1_scope policy1_apiname policy1_inboundsession policy1_outboundsession'
policy1_outboundsession_=' policy1_outboundsession_ipAddressesFrom policy1_outboundsession_ipAddressesTo'
policy_=' policy1'
```

I know, I can use xmlstarlet to create element inside my outputpolicy.xml file as given below.

```
for g in $(eval echo \$${f}_apiname); do
     echo " this policy will be applied to apis,$(eval echo \$${f}_apiname)"
    done
      if [ -z "$(eval echo \$${f}_inboundsession_)" ]; then
        echo 'the inbound session is not present'
      else
        echo 'the inbound session is present and append the policy settings to inbound'
        xmlstarlet ed -O  -s '//inbound' -t elem -n rate-limit-by-key  -i '//inbound/rate-limit-by-key' -t attr -n calls -v xx -i '//inbound/rate-limit-by-key' -t attr -n renewal-period -v yy -i '//inbound/rate-limit-by-key' -t attr -n counter-key -v '@(Regex.Match(context.x.y.GetValueOrDefault("xxxxxxx",""), @"^[.x-y]*")?.Value)' policy.xml > io_ou_ipfilter.xml
```

but what I am looking is use xmlstarlet in my script to read the output of the above script variable  "$(eval echo $${f}*inboundsession*) and insert the given string under inbound session of the below policy.xml file if the string is not preset.

Expected Output

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
      <base />
      <rate-limit-by-key calls="xxx" renewal-period="xx" counter-key="@(Regex.Match(context.x.y.GetValueOrDefault("xxxxxxx",""), @"^[.x-y]*")?.Value)" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
      <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
      <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
      <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could add the `rate-limit-by-key` node, or not if it exists.

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh disable=SC2016

xmlstarlet edit -O \
  -a '/policies/inbound/base[not(following-sibling::rate-limit-by-key)]' \
    -t elem -n 'rate-limit-by-key' \
  --var lim '$prev' \
  -s '$lim' -t attr -n 'calls' -v 'xx' \
  -s '$lim' -t attr -n 'renewal-period' -v 'yy' \
  -s '$lim' -t attr -n 'counter-key' \
    -v '@(Regex.Match(context.x.y.GetValueOrDefault("xxxxxxx",""), @"^[.x-y]*")?.Value)' \
"${infile:-file.xml}"
```

where:

- `-a …` (aka `--append`) adds a following-sibling node, it executes
  only if its argument matches an existing node and so the XPath
  [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#predicates) (`not(following-sibling::rate-limit-by-key)`)
  specifies an *add-if-not-exists* condition
- if `-a …` matches nothing then `$prev` <sup>[]</sup> will match
  nothing and this will nullify the following `$prev`-dependent `-s …`
  (aka `--subnode`) options
- the `-v` (aka `--value`) options here use string literals but they
  can be changed to pull in a shell variable (`-v "${somevar}"`)
  or the result of a command substitution ( `-v "$(somecmd)"`)

[]
In an `xmlstarlet edit` command
`--var` defines a named variable, and the back reference `$prev`
variable (aka `$xstar:prev`) refers to the node(s) created by the most
recent `-s`, `-i`, or `-a` option which all define or redefine it
(see [`xmlstarlet.txt`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet.txt)
for a few examples of `--var` and `$prev`).

---

Note that the expected output you posted is not XML as it contains
quote characters in an attribute value which an XML serializer will
likely output as `&quot;`.

Given this input file,

```xml
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base/>
  </inbound>
</policies>
```

the command above produces,

```xml
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base/>
    <rate-limit-by-key calls="xx" renewal-period="yy" counter-key="@(Regex.Match(context.x.y.GetValueOrDefault(&quot;xxxxxxx&quot;,&quot;&quot;), @&quot;^[.x-y]*&quot;)?.Value)"/>
  </inbound>
</policies>
```